# I cannot retrieve my saved data from database using Entity Framework and I'm not getting any errors

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have the following code, and am trying to retrieve the data from my database. I know the data is saving correctly, but what am I doing wrong when calling it? I use the SQL Server Object Window within Visual Studio and can see that there is information in the database in the Song table, but when I try to call it in my action method, I do not see any information being retrieved when a breakpoint is set on the .ToList() method.

MusicController.cs

```
SongDatabase db = new SongDatabase();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Music()
{
    var songs = db.Songs.ToList();
    return View(songs);
}
```

Song.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the song of the music for the playlist, and will be logged into the Music Manager app.
/// </summary>
public class Song
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The Id of the song.
    /// </summary>
    public int SongId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  The name of the song.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Song")]
    public string SongName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The artist of the song.
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(100)]
    [DisplayName("Artist")]
    public string ArtistName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents an album from an artist.
    /// </summary>
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Album")]
    public string AlbumName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  The duration of the song.
    /// </summary>
    public double Duration { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Whether or not this song should be excluded when calculating the total duration of the current playlist. 
    /// </summary>
    public bool Exclude { get; set; }
}
```

SongDatabase.cs

```
public class SongDatabase : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

    public SongDatabase()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SongDatabase>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell what make you think you doing something wrong? Error message, wrong data? Suppose `db` is datacontext, how you instantiated it?

Comment: Why are you passing the parameter `Song song`? What is the purpose behind it when you are not using it anywhere? 

Another problem might be if you have referential integrity in place in your database. You basically try to serialize your response (`return View(songs)`)in order to return it back to client but it could be that you are getting an error from JSON library that mentions potential circular reference. 

These are some of the ideas what to look at, however, throw some errors and additional code in to your question.